Is it possible in a Postman function to pass an 'enum' How would I define it.?
I have this Postman scenario. What I'd like to do is create an enum or the equivalent for the two or three schemas I look for in response bodies (i.e. success, fault, etc.)  So far, I have one success and two failure schemas.  My Java background is trying to refactor this into a 'enum' if that's possible.  I'm trying to avoid just "knowing" what schemas can be expected
utils.validateResponseSchema(pm, "successSchema")

My function works as such.
validateResponseSchema: (pm, expectedSchema) => {
    pm.test("Response schema validation successful", () => {
        pm.expect(pm.response.json()).to.have.jsonSchema(pm.collectionVariables.get(expectedSchema))
    })
}

I'm trying to refactor the 'expectedSchema' parameter into an 'enum' of sorts.  That's my question in a nutshell, and where would I define it in Postman?
To define the various expected response schemas in an Enum...

You can achive this by define as a Global Variable
If you prefer, you can define the enum directly in a global variable:

Go to "Manage Environments" in Postman.

Create a new global variable called ResponseSchemas.

Set its value to the stringified enum object:
{
"SUCCESS": "successSchema",
"FAULT_A": "faultSchemaA",
"FAULT_B": "faultSchemaB"
}


retrieve and use the ResponseSchemas enum:
validateResponseSchema: (pm, expectedSchemaKey) => {
    const responseSchemas = JSON.parse(pm.environment.get("ResponseSchemas"));
    const expectedSchema = responseSchemas[expectedSchemaKey];
    
    pm.test("Response schema validation successful", () => {


pm.expect(pm.response.json()).to.have.jsonSchema(pm.collectionVariables.get(expectedSchema));
});

}

I love the idea.   Let me try that... thank you-...  I'm drunk at the moment.

It worked.  Thank you.  I am grateful.
